# Returning CGSize with variable for UICollectionView size is causing unwanted extra spacing between cells

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a horizontal UICollectionView with cells that have different sizes depending on the amount of text in each cell. I was able to accomplish this with the code below, but it is now causing extra spacing between my cells. My minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt is already returning 0 and I have tried returning a negative number but neither is working. Does anyone know why the extra space is happening and how to get rid of it?

Just for reference, inside my cell I have a 1 UILabel that is constrained to the full dimensions of the cell.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var stringWidth: CGFloat = 100
    //Finding and setting feedMenuCellWidth
    if let groupName = groups[indexPath.item].name {
        var originalString: String = groupName
        let myString: NSString = originalString as NSString
        let size: CGSize = myString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
        stringWidth = size.width
   }
    //Returning CGSize
    return CGSize(width: stringWidth + 20, height: frame.height) // with standard width
}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum interitem spacing is just that, its the minimum, but if there is extra space, UICollectionViewFlowLayout distributes it between items.  Instead of using the default UICollectionViewLayout that comes with the collection view which is a UICollectionViewFlowLayout you should make your own concrete instance of [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout), then you can allocate all of your extra space to the left or to the right instead of distributing it between elements like UICollectionViewFlowLayout does.